# как распределить два списка по своим столбцам в библиотеке csv

Tags: python, csv

надо чтобы первый список был в одной колонке а второй список во второй.

Пример:

```
nums = [один,два,три]
words = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Примерно так должно быть:

```
один, one
два, two
три, three
```

выходит вот так:

```
одинone
дваtwo
триtrhree
```

вот код:

```
import csv

names = ['один', 'два', 'три']
desc = ['one', 'two', 'three']
final = [names,desc]
                

with open('data.csv', 'w')as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, )
    writer.writerow(('ru',
                    'uk')) 
    
for a in final,:
    with open('data.csv', 'a')as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(final)
```

Comment: и что не получается? без ваших попыток решить проблему вопрос закроют

Comment: У меня вообще ничего не выходит

Comment: @VanyaKletsov, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам сначала нужно подготовить данные для записи, а потом уже записать все за один прием.
В коде ниже обратите внимание на строчку с `zip(names, desc)`. Прочтите документацию про метод `zip` и посмотрите, что он делает с вашими данными.

```
import csv 
names = ['один', 'два', 'три']
desc = ['one', 'two', 'three']

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(('ru', 'uk')) 
    for i in zip(names, desc):
        writer.writerow(i)
```

содержимое data.csv:

```
ru,uk
один,one
два,two
три,three
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!